# How to keep page size when converting pdf to image

Tags: pdf, adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I mainly use photoshop to touch up forms I am going to serve to users. Often these forms come in pdf form with a footer.

```
 1) I pull the pdf into photoshop, and select a page. 
 2) I then select a page, eg page 1
 3) Add new layer
 4) Move layer to background -> flatten image -> export as png
 5) do for each page in pdf*
```

Typically, these forms have a footer or border which forces photoshop to recognize the item as a full page. But, I am now encountering an issue where photoshop is not recognizing it as a full page, and the layers I am adding are only for the small blurb of text. When this gets exported to a png, it loses it's size dimensions for programmatically serving the image.

How do I select a pdf page and have photoshop see it as a full page (dimension-wise) and save as a full page with trailing white-space?

Example of the small area I am trying to force to a full page.
[image: need full page]

And this is an example of a full page and how it normally pops up for me.

[image: trying to get image to be like this]

I'm not sure how to 'search' on what to do
Can't I change something here?

[image: Can't I do something here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using photoshop, use adobe acrobat dc. Select export pdf as image.
Select your file format i.e.PNG, check the export all images box. Select your destination path and click on export.
See this screenshot for reference.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: omg - I love your face! You just saved me so much time and hassle. I literally had no idea this was an option.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop doesn't care a bit for page sizes; it's just not designed that way.

Try starting with a default document the size of your intended output & placing the image on that. It should then preserve whitespace.

Comment: I added images for reference - I don't understand what you're saying to do.

Comment: I really can't understand why you want to use photoshop to do that kind of task. It looks like a task for a pdf editor, or something that would keep your text as vector instead of rasterising it.  Also, Photoshop is not "page aware" at all. It is 'pixel dimension aware'.